# Configuring Teamcity's logging behaviour

Tags: teamcity

I'm using Teamcity 5 for our CI environment. It's a great tool, but I've been struggling with one thing: the `stdout_yyyyMMdd.log` file in the `\TeamCity\logs` folder grows to ridiculous sizes. Is there a way to turn it off?

Places I've looked so far:

- Jetbrains: Nothing on stdout;
- Google for "tomcat stdout logs": the first few links don't really address the issue.

**Edit**:

At KIR's suggestion, I actually looked to see what's in stdout. It's the same exception message repeated over and over again:

```
[2010-12-01 08:57:21,268]   WARN -   jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - java.io.FileNotFoundException: <...Path...>\.BuildServer\system\caches\search\_8p.prx (The system cannot find the file specified) 
[2010-12-01 08:57:21,315]  ERROR - erverSide.search.SearchService - SearchService.enqueueHistory 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: <...Path...>\.BuildServer\system\caches\search\_8p.prx (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory$SimpleFSIndexInput$Descriptor.<init>(SimpleFSDirectory.java:78)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory$SimpleFSIndexInput.<init>(SimpleFSDirectory.java:108)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory.openInput(SimpleFSDirectory.java:65)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader$CoreReaders.<init>(SegmentReader.java:132)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:638)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:599)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.<init>(DirectoryReader.java:104)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlyDirectoryReader.<init>(ReadOnlyDirectoryReader.java:27)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader$1.doBody(DirectoryReader.java:74)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:704)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:69)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:476)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:314)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.search.SearchService.getIndexSearcher(SearchService.java:451)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.search.SearchService.enqueueHistory(SearchService.java:515)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.search.BackgroundIndexer.run(BackgroundIndexer.java:32)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea what this file is?

Comment: May be a fragment of the log would shed some light what's going on there.

Comment: @KIR: ah-ha. It seems the log file is almost entirely made out of the same Exception message. Edited original post.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running TC on unix you could use logrotate: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html (Obviously, this is a workaround but it should be effective.)

This guy has a windows equivalent that may do the trick too: http://www.datori.org/?p=7

Answer (score 0):

Remove .BuildServer\system\caches\search directory and restart TeamCity. May be this would help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by someone or something deleting the Lucene Index in Team city.
Everytime you hit a page after this it will log in stdout that it couldnt find the file.

If you clear out the whole folder which should be
%USERPROFILE%.BuildServer\system\caches\search\

See http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/TeamCity+Data+Directory for more information on where to find the folder.

And restart Teamcity it will recreate the index on start up and stop logging the error message.

Oh and search should start working again too.