# Gigs of Teamcity-javaLogging log files

Tags: logging, teamcity

Our current installation of TeamCity has 5 files each 15GB+ in size. These files are located under C:\TeamCity\logs folder.[image]

Any ideas how I can trim them? I am using 7.1.5

Here is the item that was being added over and over. At point it gave name of a .nupkg file as well, which we **manually deleted** and then everything was **good**.

```
Jan 22, 2015 12:02:06 AM net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore get
SEVERE: provider-nugetCache: Could not read disk store element for key 64367. Error was unexpected EOF in middle of data block
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected EOF in middle of data block
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.metadata.SerializableEntry.readSplitted(SerializableEntry.java:5)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.metadata.EntryImpl.readObjectInternal(EntryImpl.java:34)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.metadata.SerializableEntry.readExternal(SerializableEntry.java:16)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore.loadElementFromDiskElement(DiskStore.java:313)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore.get(DiskStore.java:268)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.searchInDiskStore(Cache.java:1290)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:904)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:879)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.cache.TypedCacheImpl.getValue(TypedCacheImpl.java:3)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.metadata.MetadataStorageImpl.getReportedKeys(MetadataStorageImpl.java:7)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.metadata.MetadataStorageImpl.removeBuild(MetadataStorageImpl.java:45)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.indexer.BuildIndexCleaner.performCleanup(BuildIndexCleaner.java:16)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.HistoryEntryCleaner.cleanupExtensionsData(HistoryEntryCleaner.java:38)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.HistoryEntryCleaner.performCleanup(HistoryEntryCleaner.java:138)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.HistoryEntryCleaner.performCleanup(HistoryEntryCleaner.java:132)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.ServerCleanupManagerImpl$3.performCleanup(ServerCleanupManagerImpl.java)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade$1$1.doInConnection(DBFacade.java:178)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade$6.doInConnection(DBFacade.java:415)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:341)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade._runSql(DBFacade.java:411)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade.access$000(DBFacade.java:33)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade$1.doInTransaction(DBFacade.java:174)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade.compact(DBFacade.java:171)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.ServerCleanupManagerImpl.startCleanup(ServerCleanupManagerImpl.java:74)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.ServerCleanupManagerImpl$2.run(ServerCleanupManagerImpl.java:0)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Jan 22, 2015 12:02:06 AM net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore remove
SEVERE: provider-nugetCache: Could not remove disk store entry for key 64367. Error was unexpected EOF in middle of data block
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected EOF in middle of data block
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.metadata.SerializableEntry.readSplitted(SerializableEntry.java:5)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.metadata.EntryImpl.readObjectInternal(EntryImpl.java:34)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.metadata.SerializableEntry.readExternal(SerializableEntry.java:16)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore.loadElementFromDiskElement(DiskStore.java:313)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore.remove(DiskStore.java:483)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.remove(Cache.java:1465)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.remove(Cache.java:1392)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.remove(Cache.java:1350)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.remove(Cache.java:1328)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.cache.TypedCacheImpl.remove(TypedCacheImpl.java:16)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.metadata.MetadataStorageImpl.removeBuild(MetadataStorageImpl.java:30)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.metadata.impl.indexer.BuildIndexCleaner.performCleanup(BuildIndexCleaner.java:16)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.HistoryEntryCleaner.cleanupExtensionsData(HistoryEntryCleaner.java:38)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.HistoryEntryCleaner.performCleanup(HistoryEntryCleaner.java:138)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.HistoryEntryCleaner.performCleanup(HistoryEntryCleaner.java:132)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.ServerCleanupManagerImpl$3.performCleanup(ServerCleanupManagerImpl.java)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade$1$1.doInConnection(DBFacade.java:178)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade$6.doInConnection(DBFacade.java:415)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:341)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade._runSql(DBFacade.java:411)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade.access$000(DBFacade.java:33)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade$1.doInTransaction(DBFacade.java:174)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFacade.compact(DBFacade.java:171)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.ServerCleanupManagerImpl.startCleanup(ServerCleanupManagerImpl.java:74)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.cleanup.ServerCleanupManagerImpl$2.run(ServerCleanupManagerImpl.java:0)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931352/configuring-teamcitys-logging-behaviour wow 41 gigs of logs in a single day?  Yasuck, TC.

Comment: @Will -- or whoever put teamcity on a server with a bad disk creating slews of exception sucks.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, problem was solved by deleting one file from the Artifacts directory. Otherwise log was just filling up with repeated entry.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the log it seems like TeamCity has a corrupted block in the cache. You might try just restarting it and seeing if that can blow the cache and get you a clean one.

Inside of TeamCity you can chose a different logging preset though I'm not sure you could avoid these -- that isn't a minor detail, that is a plea for help.

You also have jetbrains -- their support is great and they might be able to help. I would also think about upgrading as 7.1.5 is pretty dated at this point.